# istanbul cover mocha Code coverage command doesn't work

Tags: mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

I have a problem running this command ***istanbul cover _mocha*** Throws the error as follows:

```
 No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
    C:\Users\mhass\AppData\Roaming\npm\_mocha.CMD:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
                                                                  ^
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
        at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\mhass\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\hook.js:109:37)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
        at runFn (C:\Users\mhass\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\command\common\run-with-cover.js:122:16)
```

Comment: You see it's indicating the unexpected character, right?

Comment: Yeah but I ran on other files too, Same error, so may be some module is doing with me? but which?